# Calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty}n \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{e^{x/n }-1}{x}\sin x dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Calculate

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}n \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{e^{x/n}-1}{x}\sin x dx $$

I know that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \frac{e^{x/n}-1}{x} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{x/n}-1}{x/n} = 1$$

It seems plausible to think that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}n \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{e^{x/n}-1}{x}\sin x dx =  \int_0^{\pi/2}\sin x dx = 1$$

But i guess this is far from rigorous and not a valid solution.

This seems like a hard integral to solve and that i should find some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's valid so long as you can justify swapping the limit and the integral, which you can do here with dominated convergence. Note that the sequence of functions

$$g_n(x) = n \frac{e^{x/n} - 1}{x}$$

is uniformly bounded:

$$g_n(x) = n \frac{1 + (x/n) + O((x/n)^2) - 1}{x} = 1 + O(x/n)$$

Alternatively, write

$$g_n(x) = \frac{e^{x/n} - 1}{x/n}$$

Since $x$ is bounded, we can see that $g_n(x)$ converges uniformly to the constant function $\frac{d}{dx}\mid_{x = 0} e^x = 1$.

Either way, dominated convergence is applicable and the result follows.